# Cumulative plot of a function

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, simulation

I'm working on a SIR model (differential equations):

```
eqS = s'[t] == -b s[t] i[t];
eqI = i'[t] == b s[t] i[t] - k i[t];
eqR = r'[t] == k i[t];
```

I get a solution of those equations:

```
solution = NDSolve[{
eqS,
eqI,
eqR,
s[0] == 0.9999,
i[0] == 0.0001,
r[0] == 0.0000
}, {s, r, i},{t, 100}];
```

I get the individual solutions for S, I and R:

```
solutionS = First[s /. solution];
solutionI = First[i /. solution];
solutionR = First[r /. solution];
```

And I plot the solution for I:

```
Plot[{solutionI[t]}, {t, 0, 100},PlotRange -> {0, 1.01}]
```

[image: infected cases]

I'm trying to get the cumulative plot of the infected cases: the sum of the cases of the days before. How can I get it?

Answer (score 8):

Add one more equation

```
b = 1.; k = 0.1;
eqS = s'[t] == -b s[t] i[t];
eqI = i'[t] == b s[t] i[t] - k i[t];
eqR = r'[t] == k i[t];
eqCI = c'[t] == i[t];
solution = 
  NDSolve[{eqS, eqI, eqR, eqCI, 
           s[0.] == 0.9999, i[0.] == 0.0001, r[0.] == 0., c[0.] == 0.}, 
          {i, c}, {t, 100}] // First;
```

plot the function and its cumulative sum

```
Plot[{i[t], c[t]} /. solution, {t, 0, 100}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

`Integrate` on an interpolating function returns the desired function `cum`.

```
ListLinePlot[cum = Head@Integrate[solutionI[t], t]]
```

[image]